# How can I use annotations from other SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-aop

I have 2 `SpringBoot` `Apps` in the `multimodule maven` project. In first spring boot app i have implemented annotations with spring `AOP`. How can i use that `annotation` with aspect logic in my second spring app?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As your question is currently written, it is not very clear and thus difficult to answer. Please edit your question so-that it contains more details about what you want to achieve, what you have tried so far and where you failed. Also, consider including a [minimal, reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and have a look at [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: create task that builds shared items into a library jar and then store that in repo and add that as a dependency to other application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the AOP Spring Boot application as a dependency of the second one. This will give you access to the annotations.

In your AOP Spring Boot application create a `@Configuration` class that enables AOP and scans for your Aspects.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("package.of.aspects")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopConfig() {
}
```

There are multiple ways of enabling this configuration in your secondary application.

The simplest one is to use the `@Import` annotation:

```
@Import(AopConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class SecondApplication {
...
}
```

You can also make `AopConfig` an Auto Configuration by creating `AopSpringBoot/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file with this content:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  fully.qualified.name.AopConfig
```